New to Blockchain trading. Blockchain has locked my entire trading account until the 10% mining fee is payed
When I tried withdrawing a small amount of money from my trading account, I received a message from customer service that blockchain requires me to withdraw the entire amount in my trading account and then pay the 10% mining fee. Then I would be able to withdraw funds. Problem is, I thought I would be able to use some of my profits to pay the required mining fee. However, blockchain has taken control of my total balance. I do not have additional funds to purchase more USDC to pay mining fees, now or in the near future. I have 5 working days to make payment before blockchain places my entire balance in escrow at more charge. I do not have any family or friends that might be able to loan the amount. I am not able to qualify for a bank loan. WHAT CAN I DO? Will the blockchain possibly work with me? And how do I contact them to explain my rookie oversite/mistake? Am I even in the right ballpark for help?
Please and Thank you

Sorry but it looks like you are getting scammed.
